# How to disable pastdate in combodate.js?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, combodate

we are using DatePicker for combodate.js,currently it is showing past date also,i want to disable past date.so kindly give me the best solution for it.

Code is here: You can find the code here which is used by us

http://code.google.com/p/rada-solutions/source/browse/trunk/Proyectos/DIGIP/Temperatura/Proyecto/Digip+Framework/App_Theme_Responsive/js/combodate/combodate.js?spec=svn211&r=178

Comment: Please provide the code within your question. Links can be broken in the future.

Comment: code is too large.i am unable to provide the code.that is why i have provided the link which contain complete code.Please refer that link

Comment: please try to give best solutions for my query as soon as possible.

Comment: You need to provide a piece of code which is: http://sscce.org/

Comment: sir kindly look into bellow link :https://github.com/vitalets/combodate/blob/1fee64b627be07c9da243c53ed80cbf4f0f757cb/src/combodate.js

Comment: you can find complete code in above link

Comment: i hope i will get best solution for my query